# Can PV vs P plot be called an isotherm?

Tags: isotherm

Normally we call plots drawn at constant temperature as isotherms, e.g. $P$ vs $V$ plot, Langmuir isotherm etc.

Using that logic, shouldn't the $PV$ vs $P$ plots also be called isotherms?

Personally, I haven't read in any text about such plots being called isotherms.

Comment: If the T is kept constant why not? Perhaps it is not very useful to plot something that is expected to be constant for a closed system?

Comment: @Alchimista   ... Only if ideal gas is involved.

Comment: @Poutnik yes of course but it might be related to a entry level. Otherwise why the question?

Comment: @Alchimista Yes it's an entry level question by one of my student. I also thought on your lines but just wanted to confirm. :) Sometimes there are IUPAC definition or similar standard things.

Comment: All curves at constant T are or can be called isotherms. But they are often not called that way explicitly. Explicit term is usually used in scenarios where other variables could be kept constant instead, having isobars, isochores, isotropes,...